# How does this type of thru axle work?

Tags: axle, through-axle

I have a similar question to [Non-quick release through axle - a few questions](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45773/non-quick-release-through-axle-a-few-questions). My rear axle is similar to that one so I seem to be sorted from that question.

However, the front one is different. It does have a lever, but not a quick-release one I am used to or which I can find in all tutorials. It also has an allen key screw in the centre.

[image: the lever]

The manufacturer is Mr. Control (12x100mm) and from the [Catalogue](http://www.mrcontrol-bike.com/en/download/2018MrControl_CAT-view.pdf) I ques it could be the QR-MF5-12X type. The description just says "Lever can be adjusted from rotational position. Max force to 150kg".

For regular opening like changing a tube or tyre do I open the little bolt or do I use the lever? What does the little screw with much smaller torque rating? Do I need to have a torque wrench in the field with me for that one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For regular opening like changing a tube or tyre do I open the little bolt or do I use the lever?

You take the axel out by unscrewing with the lever (left loose). The bolt allows you to change the orientation of the lever relative to the axel, if you care about such things.

> What does the little screw with much smaller torque rating?

The lever usually has teeth to keep it in place so you do not need a lot of torque to keep the lever from slipping.

> Do I need to have a torque wrench in the field with me for that one?

Only if you feel that you need to change the orientation of the lever relative to the axel while out in the field. I cannot think of a valid use case.